# How can I make the output format of a video the same as the input format?

Tags: libav

How can I make the output format of a video the same as the input format for general case?

```
avconv -i source -vcodec copy -acodec copy -movflags empty_moov -f ??? output
```

I would not like to use `-f` with a specific value and how to prevent `avconv` from whatever extension to deduce format.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

> `for file in *
>
>   do
>
>   avconv -i $file -vcodec copy -acodec copy -movflags empty_moov \
>
>   -f "${file##*.}" output
>
>   done`

You could also use `${file#*.}` if the path need not be stripped.